# Why isn't my background CSS image appearing in DIV?

Tags: css, image, html

I am wanting to place an image in a DIV, but the image is for aesthetics and not content and therefore wanted to place it as a background image in the DIV, instead of using HTML to place it, but when I try and do this, it isn't appearing?

my HTML code:

```
 <div id="largec">

 </div>
```

My CSS code:

```
 #largec {
     background-image:url(large-circle.png); 
     background-size:80px 60px;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;

 }
```

Please bare in mind I am quite new to code!

Thanks

Comment: Where is the image located in relation to your css? Does it work if you link to a random image like `background-image:url(http://www.placehold.it/80/60);`?

Answer (score 6):

If your div doesn't have any content then it won't have any height. Try setting a `min-height` to that of your background image

```
#largec {
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Try to put the name of the file between " ", like this:

```
#largec {
     background-image:url("large-circle.png"); 
     background-size:80px 60px;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;

 }
```

2) Make sure that the image is in the same folder as the css code.

3) It is recomended to use only "normal" characters, number and the underscore, in the names of the files (to prevent unsuccessful links).